# NLog Logger gets wrong name

Tags: logging, windows-services, nlog

I use NLog in a windows service project. We are using EasyNetQ for messaging, and I have extended the EasyNetQLogger to have EasyNetQ-logmessages appear in my logfiles.

The class is like this:

```
public class EasyNetQLogger : IEasyNetQLogger
{

    private readonly Logger _traceLogger;

    public EasyNetQLogger()
    {
        _traceLogger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    public void DebugWrite(string format, params object[] args)
    {            
        _traceLogger.Trace(String.Format(format, args));           
    }

    public void InfoWrite(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _traceLogger.Info(String.Format(format, args));
    }

    public void ErrorWrite(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        _traceLogger.Error(String.Format(format, args));
    }

    public void ErrorWrite(Exception exception)
    {
        _traceLogger.Error("Exception in EasyNetQ", exception);
    }
}
```

When I create the bus-instance, I do it like this in my ServiceController class:

```
var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(config.MessageBus, x => x.Register<IEasyNetQLogger>(_ => new EasyNetQLogger()));
```

My logger name then becomes "ServiceController" instead of ....EasyNetQLogger. I want the EasyNetQ-message to appear in a separate file, but I cannot, since there is other stuff happening in this ServiceController class.

Does anyone know how I could achieve the desired "EasyNetQLogger" logger name?

Answer (score 0):

Defining the `_traceLogger` as static does the trick:

```
public class EasyNetQLogger : IEasyNetQLogger
{
    private static readonly Logger _traceLogger;

    static EasyNetQLogger()
    {
        _traceLogger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    //...
}
```